# CMake error while doing yotta build on Raspberry Pi

Tags: gcc

I am getting following error while I run 'yotta build' command. I am trying to install mbed client on  Raspberry Pi. I am following this tutorial [mbed client linux example](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-client-linux-example)

Error:

```
info: generate for target: x86-linux-native 1.0.0 at /home/pi/mbed-client-linux-example/yotta_targets/x86-linux-native
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
-- Check for working C compiler using: Ninja
-- Check for working C compiler using: Ninja -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

  Change Dir: /home/pi/mbed-client-linux-example/build/x86-linux-native/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/ninja" "cmTryCompileExec1896237997"

  /usr/bin/ninja: 1: /usr/bin/ninja: Syntax error: ")" unexpected





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:65 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/mbed-client-linux-example/build/x86-linux-       native/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/mbed-client-linux-example/build/x86-linux-native/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
error: command ['cmake', '-D', 'CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo', '-G', 'Ninja', '.'] failed
```

Answer (score 1):

The software you're trying to compile on the Raspberry Pi is only designed to work on an x86 platform. It will not run on the RPi.